# AngularJS Custom Directive Isolated Scope is not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to create a Spinner,

I have a custom directive in AngularJS

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', [])

.directive('spinner', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      jump:'=jump'
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.jump = 0;

      scope.spinning = function(action) { 
        var jumps = document.getElementById("jumps").value;
        var spinn = document.getElementById("spinn").innerText;
        var convt = Number(spinn);
        var jumpconvt = Number(jumps);
        if(jumps === '' && action === "add") {

          convt= convt +1;
        }
        else if(jumps === '' && action === "sub") {

          convt= convt - 1;

        }
        else if(jumps !== '' && action === "sub") {
          convt = convt - Number(jumps);

        }
        else{
          convt =  jumpconvt + convt;
        }

        document.getElementById("spinn").innerHTML = convt;

      };
    },
    templateUrl: 'spinnerDirective.html'
  };
});
```

in spinnerDirective.html will contain

```
<div>
  <div> Jumps: <input type='text' id="jumps" ng-model='count'/> </div>

  <div  style="float: left; width:120px; margin-top:10px;" >
    <div style="border-color: red;  border-style: solid; border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px; margin-left: 10px; text-align: center; height: 30px; line-height: 2px;" >
      <label style="vertical-align: top;line-height: normal;"  ng-click="spinning('add');" >+</label>
    </div>

    <div style="margin-top: -12px; text-align: center; height:12px;margin-left: 7px;">
      <span id="spinn" style="background-color: #fff;font-size:18px;">{{jump}}</span>
    </div>

    <div style="border-color: red;  border-style: solid; border-width: 0 1px 1px 1px; margin-left: 10px; text-align: center; height: 30px;line-height: 27px;">
      <label style="vertical-align: bottom;line-height: normal;"  ng-click="spinning('sub');">-</label>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Which will be rendered as:

```
<div>
  <div>Spinner</div>
  <div style="float: left;">
    <spinner jump="jump"></spinner>
  </div>
  <div style="float: left;">
    <spinner jump="jump"></spinner>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is: if I use one spinner it works fine. But When I have multiple spinners it's not working, when i do click on `+` or `-` button in 2nd spinner, count is getting change in 1st spinner.

Result should be: onlick on `+` or `-` without giving any value in textbox, value should get increment or decrement by 1, and by giving value in textbox should get add or substract by textbox value.

when i do click on `+` or `-` button on 1st Spinner changes should happen only in 1st spinner and when i do click on `+` or `-` button on 2nd Spinner changes should happen only in 2nd spinner.

I have tried isolated scope in directive but still no effect.

Here's my code (Edit): [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KPHqes1baju70oSYRdRp?p=preview)

Please if someone could guide me how to do it right.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fist of all select correct answer on your previous question you posted on same program.

Comment: Secondly do not use document. Getelementsbyid. It is selecting your first spenear allways.

Comment: There's a real miss match of angular and native JS there. Your using `document.getElementById` to get the value of an input you have already bound `ngModel` to. Then you setting the `innerHTML` of an element you've already bound to with `{{jump}}`. You really need to stick to one paradigm or the other, not merging them together.

Comment: I have updated my Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/KPHqes1baju70oSYRdRp?p=preview   but i'm facing another issue, var spinn = document.getElementById("spinn").innerText; here i'm getting the problem. getting the value from label, Please help me to resolve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for the support i resolve my issue..